# MongoDB Windows repaired db not starting

Tags: mongodb

I attempted to upgrade a MongoDB instance (4.0.9) to version 4.2.0.
After stopping the service, replacing the files in the bin folder, the service refused to start, stating that

```
 Data directory D:\data\db\ not found., terminating
```

I do have a different directory set in my mongod.cfg but after upgrading, mongo simply ignores it. I tried running

```
 mongod --repair
```

And it repairs the indexes and the db but then it won't start because of the same error, so I did

```
mongodb --repair --dbpath d:\Server\MONGO\data
```

Which repairs again the db but if I start the service I get again the same error

```
Data directory D:\data\db\ not found., terminating
```

So I backed up my data folder, removed mongo, reinstalled it and it starts. If I overwrite the data folder, it won't start even after a repair.

I'm trying to not lose my data. From a fresh install, what files should I overwrite to be able to do a repair and keep my old data?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the service: `net stop MongoDB`, `mongod.exe --remove`, `mongod.exe --config "path_to_config" --install`, `net start MongoDB` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of searching and error testing, I have figured out the issue.
For some reason I had a working 4.0.9 build that was using a never upgraded dataset, which I do not understand yet why it would even work before upgrading to 4.2.0...

So it seems to be that the dataset format was not WiredTired but still mmapv1 from a 2.x build. Fixed it by

- duplicating the dataset to make it available in `d:\Data\db`
- forcing the mmapv1 data format by downgrading to a 2.x version `mongod --dbpath [myPath] --storageEngine=mmapv1`
- moving my way up to 3.4.x then 3.6.x then 4.0, reusing my old data set and repairing and upgrading at each version...